# Could I format my C: Drive by mistake?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, operating-systems, formatting

Could you accidentally reformat a C: drive using file explorer? Would it be remotely possible?

I'm just wondering if this can happen - is it possible to accidentally click the format button on "Local Disk C" and format, or is there security in place to prevent this from happening?

I'm just scared when I right click my drive then hover down to properties in fear of accidentally reformatting. My PC's well, clean install, but hovering over the format button gets me worried, especially passing right through it.

I'm new to computing and Windows in general.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "accidentally formatted"? There are few steps required to format a drive, you'd need to be drunk or something for it to be accidental in the 1st place. Just clicking in the right click menu doesn't go  straight into formatting, which you can test with e.g. a pendrive.

Comment: It’s not clear what you are worried about if you attempting to perform a clean install of Windows. You should edit your question and clarify it, in it’s current form, your question cannot be answered

Comment: i meant by like when you right click the drive and pass the format button can you accidentally press it? what happens if you do press it? does it pop up the ui when you need to reformat a pen drive or a usb thing? im just anxious but yeah

Comment: I think we're being a bit harsh on a new user here. No-one is born knowing how computers work. Seeing the Format option on your boot drive could be worrying if you don't know there are safeguards in place to prevent you destroying your entire system with a single mis-click.

Comment: Why not run up a VM, install Windows (skip entering a key when it asks and you will get a trial version) and then find out?

Comment: I think it's also a bit much to expect someone new to computing to know how to 'run up a VM'.

Comment: @Tetsujin - The issues with this question have little to do with the user being new to the community or new to using a computer in general.

Comment: @Ramhound - it took me five minutes to fix the question & add an answer. We bite newbies too hard here, it's often been said. Pile on rather than a quick fix.

Comment: I didn’t pile on I attempted to instruct. Would do more but on  won’t do more until answers that are generated by OpenAI and similar LLM are totally banned from the platform.

Comment: @Tetsujin I wasn't meaning to "pile on", a VM is a perfectly good sandbox for experimenting in a way that is unlikely to harm the main computer and there are hundreds of guides on how to do it on the internet. I did not downvote, I did not vote to close, I just suggested something that could be an interesting excursion into experimentation that would alleviate fears in a practical manner. Granted my comment could have been written better, but I was pressed for time.

Comment: Well, the pile on worked, the sheep closed it & continued to downvote even after it was fixed; I've voted to re-open. It was a bit vague but it was quite clear what the intent was [even though one commenter didn't get it, it *was* actually quite clear, if not well-stated. There's now nothing wrong with it, yet the pile on continued, long after the vagaries were fixed. This site suffers badly from newbie-biting. This is not the way to gain users.

Answer (score 4):

Most operating systems will not let you saw off the branch you're sitting on, unless you get deep under the hood with unix commands.

Firstly, notice the ellipsis … [three dots] after the Format command. This tells you that you will be presented with more options if you click it. It will not just happen straight away.

[image]

If this was a non-boot drive you would then be asked exactly how you would like to format. As it is the system boot drive, instead you get this - a flat refusal to let you wreck your system…

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the scuffles but i am anxious when it comes to these things i overthink over the most little things when it comes to these because i dont wanna break any components or something like that.

Comment: No worries. Different users have different interpretations when they first see a question. I thought it was clear enough in intent to tidy it up a bit & answer. Some are less patient. Don't let that put you off :)